# mSigna : return address

Tags: transaction-fees, msigna

I installed mSigna, connected it to a full node and created an address.
Assumed I bought 1BTC from some exchange platform and it is received on this address. How can I spend 10 mBTC without paying a transaction fee of 990 mBTC ?
Does mSigna create automatically a return address and automatically pays 990 - the transaction fee I chose to this address or must I do it by hand ?
Thanks.
Francis

Answer (score 1):

mSIGNA creates a change address for you. You do need to tell it what fee you want to pay - we are working on adding better automatic fee estimation, but for now you need to specify it yourself.